# Jquery fullscreen image with Jquery scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fullscreen

I am using 2 different jquery plugins which both works fine but for some reason I can't get them to work together.

fullscreen image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     var FullscreenrOptions = {  width: 1024, height: 439, bgID: '#bgimg' };
     // This will activate the full screen background!
     jQuery.fn.fullscreenr(FullscreenrOptions);

</script>
```

scroll to div function:

```
function GotoSection(divid)
{
     $('#realBody').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + divid).offset().top}, 300);
    }
```

my html:

```
<!-- This is the background image -->
<img id="bgimg" src="img/background6.jpg" />
<!-- Here the "real" body starts, where you can put your website -->
<div id="realBody">
<div id="header">
    <div class="content">
         <img src="img/logo.png" align="left"/>
        <ul id="menu">
             <li><a id="mhome" name="home" class="selected" onclick="GotoSection('home');">Home</a></li>  
                    </ul>
             <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="home" class="seperator"></div>
            here is my home content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
#bgimg {
position:absolute;
z-index: -1;
}

#realBody{
position:absolute;
z-index: 5; /* Place the new body above the background image */
overflow:auto;  /* restore scrollbars for the content */
height:100%;width:100%; /* Make the new body fill the screen */
top:120px;
}


body
{
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #ffffff;  
padding: 0;
margin: 0;  
font-family:'HelveticaLTStdLight';
color:#0f508e;
}
```

The scroll is messed up it doesn't go to the divs that i send. I think my error is in this line:

```
$('#realBody').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + divid).offset().top}, 300);
```

but not sure what i need to change it to.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatched number of opening and closing div's.  Try correcting this and seeing if it fixes it.